Why is my animation rendering in a different colour from the one intended?
The first Image is the rendered animation. The second Image is what I created and what I intend to render. However, I keep getting the output in totally different shade colours from what I designed.

Hello and welcome to BSE. What image? I don't see any images in your post :)

Hello, Michael.. no images .. ( BTW.. not necessarily the problem, but you are aware render previews and renders have different lighting set-ups? )  I'm just going to close this for a while, for you to include the referenced images. As soon as you do, we'll re-open. There have been a couple of issues with the uploading system recently, this might not be your fault.

Hi. I have added images now. Please help with suggestions on how to fix this problem. Cheers

It seems that you are rendering a completely different scene ! Do you check in the Outliner panel Hide in Viewport vs Disable in Renders settings ? Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?
